# Unable to update Column of DBF using jdbf

Tags: java, dbf

I have a 'DBF' file with me I have Read the files successfully using the code as following:

```
public static void main(String args[])
        throws Exception
    {

        DBFReader dbfreader = new DBFReader("./book2.dbf");

        int i;
        for (i=0; i<dbfreader.getFieldCount(); i++) {
          System.out.print(dbfreader.getField(i).getName()+"  ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(i = 0; dbfreader.hasNextRecord(); i++)
        {
            Object aobj[] = dbfreader.nextRecord(Charset.forName("GBK"));
            for (int j=0; j<aobj.length; j++)
              System.out.print(aobj[j]+"  |  ");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Total Count: " + i);
    }
```

I have referred 'https://code.google.com/p/jdbf/' to do this.

I need to update the columns of my 'DBF' file. I have tried a lot but unable to get code. Please help me guys??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/iryndin/jdbf - another Java DBF read/write library made with simplicity and ease of use in mind. It is used in many production apps. It can read/write MEMO files as well. 
Please give it a try.